# SSMS import large table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm trying to move several tables of data between 2 MSSQL 2008 databases, I have generated data insert scripts for one table which is quite large (around 3.5M rows) The script is around 3GB. When I try and open the script with SSMS I get the following error:

[image]

Is there a way to get SSMS to let me open this script or to export the data into some other format which is easier to import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first big problem is that you're trying to load 3GB of data as a script into SSMS. I'm not sure how clever SSMS is but I bet it's trying to load the whole file into memory which will cause it to blow up because it's a 32 bit app - 32 bit apps have a max address space of 4GB of which 2GB is available to the process.

You'd be better off using the bulk import/export tools for this job, they're more suited for moving large blobs of data around:

> [About Bulk Import and Bulk Export Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187042.aspx)

You probably also don't want (I suspect) to run this as a transactional insert either:

> [Optimizing Bulk Import Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421.aspx)
>
> [Prerequisites for Minimal Logging in Bulk Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422.aspx)

Comment: I think you're right, I'm going about it wrong exporting as a script, ill take a look at bulk import/export stuff and try that way

Comment: `bcp` ftw​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

You can try running this script using sqlcmd from the command line.